# Set up Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, macosx

I downloaded the VirtualBox and added the `saasbook-vm-0.9.1.vdi`.

When I start the virtual machine I'm getting a prompt:

```
Press ESC in 0 seconds to skip startup.nsh or any key to continue
Shell>
```

What am I missing? What should I do next?

I'm using a Mac with OSX 10.7.5

Answer (score 3):

You have enabled EFI boot in VirtualBox.

Either type `exit` in the EFI prompt and try to find the EFI file for booting Ubuntu if you're committed to booting in EFI. Play around with the options in their EFI configuration menu. If it's not working, disable EFI in the System properties for your virtual machine and install Ubuntu into BIOS mode.

EFI isn't too much fun in VirtualBox and you don't gain *too* much from using it, unless you're trying to boot from a raw local disk, in which case it could be essential.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You may want to disable EFI support in your VirtualBox settings and try loading Ubuntu in the VM again.

I hope this helps.